# Send email asynchronously from an WCF 4 REST service

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have a WCF 4 REST service which does some processing and then returns back immediately. Now there is a need to send an email asynchronously every time this service is called. Is there some way I can achieve this without needing to queue the email in a DB and then use a Windows service to send out the email?

Comment: can't you simply use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(YourSendEmailMethod)` ?

Comment: Is it a good idea to use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem with WCF? Will this not reduce to the number of threads available to service the REST webservice?

Comment: don't know if there is impact with WCF, but the idea of the ThreadPool is to do the job when it's possible i.e. when a thread is freed. Of course this will consume a thread, but whatever the path you will choose, there will allways have a thread somewhere to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used it, but [`SmtpClient.SendAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) seems to be the right tool for the job.

From MSDN, emphasis mine:

> Sends the specified e-mail message to
>   an SMTP server for delivery. This
>   method **does not block the calling
>   thread** and allows the caller to pass
>   an object to the method that is
>   invoked when the operation completes.

This way your service can return immediately after posting the request to send the email and you can even register a callback to know when the send email operation completes.